# Admin permissions denied when trying to move a file to trash on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions

How do I regain my admin permissions in Ubuntu 18.04?

I am getting the following error from Ubuntu:
`Unable to trash file /home/bob/Desktop/install: Permission denied`

Why?

Comment: When does this message appear? When you try to delete the file in a file manager, or do you use some command like `rm` in a terminal? Anyway, can you tell us the ownership and permissions of that file? To do so, open a terminal and type `ls -l /home/bob/Desktop/install`. That info about the containing directory would be useful, as well: `ls -ld /home/bob/Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

I echo Stefan's comment.

I would try

```
sudo rm -f /home/bob/Desktop/install
```

"sudo" is the command that will attempt to use administrator permissions to perform an action such as rm (remove)

edit: This should be done in the terminal (linux command-line)

Comment: While this command indeed succeeds in deleting the file, the question remains as to why the user `bob` is denied permission to delete the file `/home/bob/Desktop/install`, as he should be able to do so, having write permission for the directory `Desktop` normally.

Comment: Good point. Definitely will need the information you ask for then! Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I I am denied permission when I right click on a file in desktop and click move to trash  Bob baker

Comment: Could you go into the directory where that file is in the terminal?

Open up the terminal application

Type

    `cd /home/bob/Desktop`

and then type 

    `ls -l`
, Then please copy and paste the results into a comment on here.

Comment: @bobbaker: Could you also do `ls -ld .` after doing `cd /home/bob/Desktop` and post the result in a comment or edit it into your question?